# Receive MMS message in Twillio

Tags: twilio

Does anyone know how I can receive an MMS through Twilio? I checked online and found software to receive an SMS but not an MMS, since it's a new feature.  The number I have is MMS-enabled.  If I can receive it through an app, on email, anything would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

As long as your Twilio phone number is MMS-enabled you can receive MMS messages with it. Twilio currently offers MMS-enabled Twilio phone numbers in Canada and MMS-enabled Twilio short codes in the US.

If someone sends an MMS to your Twilio phone number or short code, Twilio is going to make an HTTP request to the Messages URL you have configured for your phone number.  That request is going to include a bunch of parameters:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

For each media element included in the MMS message, the Twilio request will include a MediaUrl parameter that has a URL you can use to grab the media element.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome... One final question.  Say the number is from canada and is mms enabled.  Can that number send an MMS to a regular US mobile phone number?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Today with a standard 10 digit phone number, you can only send from an MMS-enabled Canadian number to another Canadian number.

Comment: @DevinRader, I am starting with Twilio now and I can not seem to get the right code to get the media.  Even when I try to echo the number of media attached to an image, it shows nothing at all.

Comment: @ntgCleanercan you post a new question with the code you are using and any errors you are seeing

Answer (score 1):

If you have a twilio number, and it is indeed MMS enabled, you should first verify that it is actually getting where its supposed to go. Not only does the twilio number need to support MMS, whatever number you are sending needs to as well.

After you send a test MMS to your twilio number, log into you account and check the message log - if you don't see it there, one of your numbers isn't supported.

https://www.twilio.com/user/account/log/sms

if you can't see the message in the log, no code is going to help.

If the message is indeed making it to your twilio number, then this is the relevant documentation on how to receive MMS  in your app:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/message